# I am getting an output on the computer from a formula which I am not able to understand

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, education

((n - Math.Abs(j / 2) - 1) * (n - Math.Abs(j / 2))) / 2 + i + 1

this line of code is giving output of 1 for values set
n=4;j=7;i=0

when i do manually on paper i am getting 0/3 =0 what am i doing wrong
and what is this formula called provided this formula exists.

To further elborate my manual calculation

```
step 1:   ((4-Math.Abs(7/2)-1) *(4-Math.Abs(7/2)))/2+0+1

step 2:   ((4-Math.Abs(3.5)-1) *(4-Math.Abs(3.5)))/3
```

__________________________________________^ this "3" is wrong!!!!

```
step 3:   ((0.5-1) *(0.5))/3

step 4:   ((-0.5)*(0.5))/3

step 5:  (-0.25)/3

step 6:  0/3=0


 i am getting zero
 but computer is giving 1 as output
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When calculating by hand, your final step should be two additions, not a division.

Comment: That is, what you've written will be parsed as "$(\mathrm{stuff}/2) + 2 + i + 1$".

Comment: You are evaluating the "....$2+i+1$" to early. That's not how the computer will do it.

Comment: oh ok i see you say 2+i+1 will be a addition not  a division ok let me try it manually sir.

Comment: What you've written means $(\cdots/2)+i+1$. What you apparently want is $\cdots/(2+i+1)$.

Comment: See "order of operations".

Comment: (.../2)+i+1 - this works i didn't know how it translates when calculating manually thank full to @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC,@mr_e_man thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming integer division.

```
((4-Math.Abs(7/2)-1)*(4-Math.Abs(7/2)))/2 + 0 + 1
((4-3-1)*(4-3))/2+0+1
(0*1)/2+0+1
0/2+0+1
0+0+1
1
```